# Prevent XSS while still showing original characters in Input tag

Tags: java, xss, owasp, esapi

I am using OWASP ESAPI for preventing XSS attack. I am using `ESAPI.encoder().encodeForHTML((String)request.getAttribute("value"))` 
according to their recommendation, however the value is shown as escaped, like value of `test (11)` is shown as `test &#40;11&#41;` for input tag. I have also tried with JSTL  tag, but same result. Is there any way by which browser treat the value as JUST data not as script, so that the vale can be shown in its original form.

Comment: use ESAPI.encoder().encodeForHTMLAttribute() for attributes

Comment: tried ESAPI.encoder().encodeForHTMLAttribute() but same behavior.

Comment: Its solved. Actually the Value to shown was being escaped in a filter :). Thanks

Comment: @Shayan Pls post your answer below in answer section so that its better visible and may help some one.